# GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, group-by

Codeigniter/MYSQL returns this error

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.segment.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

How I can fix this? Yesterday works fine.

In the console if I use SET sql_mode = '' before execute the Query works fine but Codeigniter return the same error.

EDIT: Solved

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_‌​DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_‌​AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_‌​ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Comment: the sql_mode = only_full_group_by is starting for mysql 5.7 .. may your db env now use this mysql version or  you have changed sql mode..

Comment: can you publish here your sql query just error is not sufficient.

Comment: The easy way is to change CI's configuration to remove the only full group by sql mode. The real solution is to rewrite your query to comply with the sql standards by including all non-aggregated fields in the group by list (in MySQL v5.7 functionally dependent fields may be left out). There are quite a few questions on this already on SO.

Comment: Finally I can change the sql_mode

SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Rewrite the querys is the best idea, but is a lot of time, especially when in Production use older version.

Comment: Works great as quick fix until you have time to rewrite the queries.